# Simple example of PDF in JavaScript to display current time?

Tags: javascript, security, pdf

I am looking for a simple example that will put JavaScript in a PDF file so that the PDF displays the current time when it is opened. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow is not there to replace google.

Comment: @RobW, that's a PDF reader in JavaScript. I want to embed JavaScript inside the PDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the make-pdf-javascript tool by Didier Stevens
http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/